# iOS - Gift app I have developed

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to gift the app (without it costing me anything) that I have developed for my beta testers? Or is the only way to make the app free and then tell my beta users to download it for free and then make it paid again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go onto iTunes Connect and go into your app and then press 'Details' below the icon of the app, there is an option called 'Promo Codes' - this will provide you with a number of codes, depending on how many you want. You can then distribute these codes and they can be redeemed in the store so they can download your app for free.

```
iTunes Connect -> Applications -> [Your App] -> Details Button -> Promo Codes
```

Comment: Aha, I had no clue that existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Promo Codes?